# How do I link to a view and then be able to navigate back as if you'd come from somewhere else with TTNavigator?

Tags: iphone, three20, ttnavigator

I've got an iPhone app with a tab bar. The 1st tab shows a map, the 2nd a table view of points on the map and with the third I want a sort of shortcut to link to add a point on the map. While I can link to that view ok it doesn't let me navigate back when I save or cancel the new point. I want it to take me to the table view when you save or cancel as if I had navigated through that way.

I tried specifying the parent in [map from: parent: toSharedViewController:] but that isn't working. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of the view it is? Here is the idea, put you map to the scroll view and you can always scrollRectToVisible:rect. where rect would be the visible area which you want to show.

Comment: I've already got the map view and points table views working with a UITabBarController thanks. Just trying to work on jumping to the "new point" view whilst being able to navigate back as if I'd come from the points table view.

Comment: I have already given the idea, i do not know where you are stuck ?